# flow creating duplicate cases

Tags: visual-workflow, case

im working on a flow that creates a case for a picklist field on the Account object.
the picklist has over 10 values, and the flow should create a case for every value that is picked.

the only issue is when there is a new picklist value chosen, it creates a case for the new value, as well as the other previous values.

*for example: i choose red,  yellow. the flow creates a case for "red" and another case for "yellow"
the next day i pick another value from the picklist "orange" .... the flow will create a case for "orange" as well as a duplicate "red" and "yellow" even though those cases were created already the day before...*

here is the current logic im using.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if an account already has "red" selected but you need to create another red case for it today?

Comment: you'll have to query for Cases already attached to the Account to see what was previously created (e.g.. the red, yellow Cases) --

Comment: Agreed with the comments above. If this is an _update_ Flow (_insert_ could be OK) you're in for a world of complexity trying to make this effective and your best option is likely an Apex trigger if it's available to you.

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding your context here, could you please try passing the picklist value also to check for the duplicate case along with accountId and recordType, to avoid returning multiple case records.